# How can I convert Solaris Containers to something VMWare or VirtualBox can use?

Tags: solaris, vmware, virtualbox

I have a number of application environments based in Solaris containers.  Is there some method to take those environments and port them to something usable by either VMWare Workstation or Sun VirtualBox?  Both the source and target hardware is x86, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to migrate a container to a new computer. See for example https://www.sun.com/offers/details/moving_containers.xml. You could set up a VM to be the new container host, then migrate the container into the VM.

Answer (score 0):

not automatically, that I know of anyway.  but you should be able to spin up a vm in about 2-5 min in virtual box or vmware.  moving the apps is where the work is, but it all depends on how you set things up in the zones.  If the systems are all in one or a few directories then just move them over and configure it again.  How many zones are you talking about?  Besides this is an opportunity to clean thing up, if needed, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I should only need to move 1 zone, and thankfully it should require little cleanup.

The reason I need to be able to move from a container into VirtualBox or VMWare is to be able to demo the software locally; some markets don't have good Internet connectivity, and thus demos over the 'Net don't go well.

Comment: I don't know much about your app but can't you just check it out of version control and build/config it in the vm?  it seems you may be approaching this oddly.

Comment: My apologies for the very late response: it's not a question of just building the app, unfortunately.  The container in question contains an entire demo environment, including a substantial amount of data that can't easily be exported/imported.